# Conditional value filtering

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

**Sample data**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  day = c(3,8,14,29,4,6,8,1,4,9),
  value = c(75, 101, 115, 120, 110, 106, 122, 100, 128, 140))
```

**The idea behind the question:**

Select the smallest **day** for each **ID** subject and multiply the **value** feature by 1.3 (ID 1 - day 3 - value 75, ID 2 - day 4 - value 110, ID 3 - day 1 - value 100). 
Then compare that newly created **value** with other **values** that have the same **ID**, but have different **day** number.

**For example:**

The smallest **day** number for **ID** 1 is 3. Then multiply the **value** of that row by 1.3 (75 * 1.3 = 97.5). Compare the newly created **value** (97.5) with the **values** ((101, 115, 120)) that have the same **ID** of 1. Then anwser TRUE or FALSE if the new value is greater than **values** ((101, 115, 120)).

Repeat that as well for **ID** 2 and 3.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  day = c(3,8,14,29,4,6,8,1,4,9),
  value = c(75, 101, 115, 120, 110, 106, 122, 100, 128, 140))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(v = value[day == min(day)] * 1.3,
         flag = value > v) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#      ID   day value     v flag 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1     1     3    75  97.5 FALSE
# 2     1     8   101  97.5 TRUE 
# 3     1    14   115  97.5 TRUE 
# 4     1    29   120  97.5 TRUE 
# 5     2     4   110 143   FALSE
# 6     2     6   106 143   FALSE
# 7     2     8   122 143   FALSE
# 8     3     1   100 130   FALSE
# 9     3     4   128 130   FALSE
#10     3     9   140 130   TRUE
```

If you want to flag `ID`s with at least one `TRUE` `flag` you can create `flag2` like this:

```
 df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(v = value[day == min(day)] * 1.3,
         flag = value > v,
         flag2 = max(flag)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#      ID   day value     v flag  flag2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <int>
# 1     1     3    75  97.5 FALSE     1
# 2     1     8   101  97.5 TRUE      1
# 3     1    14   115  97.5 TRUE      1
# 4     1    29   120  97.5 TRUE      1
# 5     2     4   110 143   FALSE     0
# 6     2     6   106 143   FALSE     0
# 7     2     8   122 143   FALSE     0
# 8     3     1   100 130   FALSE     1
# 9     3     4   128 130   FALSE     1
#10     3     9   140 130   TRUE      1
```

Or extract the `ID`s as a vector:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(v = value[day == min(day)] * 1.3,
         flag = value > v) %>%
  ungroup() -> df2

df2 %>% 
  filter(flag == TRUE) %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  pull(ID)

#[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thank you AntoniosK! What is the reason of using ungroup in this particular case?

Comment: I don't want the grouping (on `ID`) to remain on my output dataset, because I might need to perform further calculations and the grouping might affect those. It's a good practice to ungroup whenever you have reached your ideal output at a particular stage of your process.

Comment: One more questions? How would you select all ID's that one or more flag feature's value is TRUE?

Comment: Do you want to get those IDs as a vector? Do you want another column in your dataset?

Comment: I figured it out for column: 

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(any(flag == "TRUE")) %>% 
  ungroup()

Thank you.Your solution for extracting ID as a vector is great thing to know.